# Drawing a Chess Board

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to draw a 8x8 chess board using C#. Here's my first attempt to draw it. It won't draw the board and I haven't found what I'm missing.

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(8 * 100, 8 * 100);
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
  Color color1, color2;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
      color1 = Color.Black;
      color2 = Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
      color1 = Color.White;
      color2 = Color.Black;
    }
    SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(color1);
    SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(color2);

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
      if (j % 2 == 0)
        g.FillRectangle(blackBrush, i * 100, j * 100, 100, 100);
      else
        g.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, i * 100, j * 100, 100, 100);
    }
  }
  g.DrawImage(bm, 150, 200);
}
```

Comment: what happens with this code?

Comment: `g.DrawImage(bm, 150, 200);` does distort your board, try `g.DrawImage(bm, 200, 200);`

Comment: Yes, I have noticed before and fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `BackgroundImage = bm;` to the bottom of your code.

You are drawing the board fine, just not displaying the bitmap...

Edit: im not sure if you're interested, but i rewrote this code.

```
int sqaureWidth = 100;
int sqaureHeight = 100;
int rowCount = 8;
int columnCount = 8;

Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(sqaureWidth * columnCount, sqaureHeight * rowCount);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
        {
            if ((j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0) || (j % 2 != 0 && i % 2 != 0))
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, i * sqaureWidth, j * sqaureHeight, sqaureWidth, sqaureHeight);
            else if ((j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 != 0) || (j % 2 != 0 && i % 2 == 0))
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, i * sqaureWidth, j * sqaureHeight, sqaureWidth, sqaureHeight);
        }
    }
}
BackgroundImage = bm;
```

also this project could help if you want to make a chess game: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20736/C-C-CLI-Micro-Chess-Huo-Chess

Comment: Very good. Notice that chess board starts with white corner at top left and the same for lowest right corner. The strange thing is that if I use your code with boards of size between 2x2,...,7x7 it works perfectly but not with 8! I mean the limit for the main 2 for loops does not work as coded. It produce such a large number of squares and its not obvious why?

Comment: @NoChance Fixed it. I wrote this ages ago, I should have used variables. So you want to make different sizes?

Comment: You can simplify it more by getting rid of those two using-blocks for brushes and just use `Brushes.White` and `Brushes.Black`.  Those don't need to be disposed.

Comment: Thanks for responding, It still produces more than 8x8 matrix! I can't figure this out!

Comment: @NoChance Ask a new question, show your code and if someone else doesnt answer it, I will.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Variables
        int rowSize = 8;
        int colSize = 8;
        //Calculation
        for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) //Loop throw ROW's
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < colSize; col++) //Loop throw COL's
            {
                if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) //Check if cells is EVEN
                {
                    Console.Write("X"); //White square
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("O"); //Black square
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(); //Switch to a new line
```

Consider a chessboard decomposed into rows and columns (horizontal and vertical). Apply indexing of rows 0 through 8 through a for loop. The same for the columns. For each square check if the sum of the indexing of the line with the column gives "par" (the rest of the division by 2 gives 0), then equals to white square. Otherwise, it assigns a black square. The trick is ((row + col)% 2). It gives values of 0 or 1, alternately. At the end of each iteration of the columns "for loop", the line changes.

Comment: https://github.com/JaviHerAr/DEV204x---CSharp---edX/blob/master/Module_2_Assignment.cs

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, you could also skip drawing the other colored tiles, and just fill the background first with the secondary color, then iterate the primary color tiles. Example:

```
    public static class GridGenerator
    {
        public static void CreateGridBackground()
        {

            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen();
            context.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, null, new Rect(0, 0, 256, 512));
            for (int xRow = 0; xRow < 256 / 16; xRow++)
            {
                for (int yColumn = 0; yColumn < 512 / 16; yColumn++)
                {
                    if ((yColumn % 2 == 0 && xRow % 2 == 0) || (yColumn % 2 != 0 && xRow % 2 != 0))
                    {
                        context.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(xRow * 16, yColumn * 16, 16, 16));
                    }
                }
            }
            context.Close();

            RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(256, 512, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            bmp.Render(visual);

            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
            encoder.Save(new FileStream("C:/Users/Krythic/Desktop/Test.png", FileMode.Create));
        }
    }
```

This is theoretically 50% faster (haven't actually benchmarked so feel free to treat this as an imaginary number), because you're cutting the drawing in half by filling one of the colors instead of actually drawing it as individual tiles. Just saying; take it or leave it.